# Companion Objects of Scala's Traits

Tags: scala, traits, companion-object

I have something like this:

```
trait AO extends A {
  private var link: String = "AO"
  //...
}
trait AR extends A {
  private var link: String = "AR"
  //...
}    

object AO extends AO with Atr {
  atr += link
}

object AR extends AR with Atr {
  atr += link  
}

trait Atr {
  import scala.collection.mutable._
  val atr: ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer()
  def echo() = {
    for(f <- atr) println("attribute: " + f)
  }
}

object TestF {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    AR.echo //not what I want!
    AO.echo //not what I want!
    echo() //doesn't show nothing...
  }
}
```

How I can add such attributes in a ListBuffer, let say like `atr`, and read them all at once like in the third line on TestF?

Comment: First, I made them `private` because I am going to use them only by that specific `class/trait Atr` (it compiles but it's not mandatory to be private). Second, I wanted to put an attribute of all the `traits` in a list and to be able to read it before mixing those traits in a class or object in runtime.

Comment: I am compiling :D, and it compiles because the private members can be seen between an abstract class/trait and their companion objects.

Comment: Do you want that third echo to display `attribute: AR, attribute: AO`?

Comment: @ggovan, yes like a list..and instead of attributes string, I can pass the names of the Types directly with `val link = this.getClass().getSimpleName()`